# array string to int, highcharts, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, vb.net

making a chart using the highcharts, trying to get data from a datatable on VB.NET, to an array, then to jason, and back to javascript to call it. but the data is not comming up on the chart, my first guess is its showing as a string...

code in javascript

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var a = $("#hidden").val();  
   var array = JSON.parse(a)
   }

  </script>
 {
     name: 'John',
     data: a
  },
```

it shows the numbers as array but data doesnt show

code in vb:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreLoad

     Dim dt As DataTable = GetTable()

     Dim array As New ArrayList
    For Each row In dt.Rows
        array.Add(row("M"))

    Next row
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim arrayJson As String = serializer.Serialize(array)

    hidden.Value = arrayJson

End Sub
```

Function GetTable() As DataTable

```
    Dim table As New DataTable

     table.Columns.Add("M")
    table.Columns.Add("T")
    table.Columns.Add("W")

    '  rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
    table.Rows.Add(2005)
    table.Rows.Add(0)
    table.Rows.Add(0)
    table.Rows.Add(0)
    table.Rows.Add(4000)
    table.Rows.Add(0)


    Return table
End Function
```

Comment: Show $("#hidden").val();

Comment: what do you mean, because when i debug i can see it showing all the data, but it shows it as string, but doesnt come up on the chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to parse data into `object` before set data to charts.

```
var a = $("#hidden").val();
JSON.parse(a);
```

Comment: i have, but it still shows as

"["2005, "0", "0", "0", "4000", "0"]" when i debug.

but the data doesnt not come up on the chart

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an answer to the question, but can't you use a wrapper like [DotNetHighcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/)
to spare yourself from the serializing hassle?

Comment: i need to use an array, and the only way is this, but not showing the data